# Is it possible to create event with multiple date/time (out of box)

Tags: datetime, events, calendar

I have an event that runs from Monday to Sunday from 9am to 6am but on Thursday the time is from 9m to 8pm.

How can I add repeat dates with diffrent time for Thursday?

Comment: Are you using a calendar plugin?  If so, which one?

Comment: You can make multiple fields or set the Startdate / Enddate in a supertable with multiple rows? (so you can add more then one).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a while ago, however you could do something like:

Default Times: 09:00-18:00 
Monday Time: 
Tuesday Time:
Wedneday Time:
Thursday Time: 09:00-20:00 
Friday Time: 
Saturday Time:
Sunday Time:

When listing times check if that day has a specific time, otherwise use the default time. Will save you changing 6 times anytime there is a change in opening times.

Not a complex solution but one that can be easily understood by a content manager.